# I can't change tabBar SelectedIndex

Tags: ios, swift, uitabbarcontroller

I try to change Tabbar selected item according to selected button tag.But nothing happens. This my button Control class.

```
class ButtonControl {
    public func controlMoreButtons(sender:UIButton){
        let board = UIStoryboard.init(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
        let tabbar = board.instantiateViewController(identifier: "mainTabBar") as! MainTabBarController
      
        let tag = sender.tag
        switch tag {
        case 1:
            tabbar.selectedIndex = 2
           print("1")
        case 2:
            print("2")
        case 3:
            print("3")
        default:
            print("unknown")
        }
        
    }
}
```

This is my Button action :

```
@IBAction func seeMoreButtonClicked(_ sender: UIButton) {
        let buttonControl = ButtonControl()
        buttonControl.controlMoreButtons(sender: sender)
        
    }
```

Comment: In my button action.

Comment: control Buttons function in another class. I called function  in my button action method. I try put all of the codes directly from action but again nothings change. and function is working I can see the prints

Comment: I present the Tabbar. I just want to change index according to the button click

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1- Add

```
class ButtonControl {
    weak var tab:UITabBarController?
```

2- Then

```
let buttonControl = ButtonControl()
buttonControl.tab = self.tabBarController
```

3- Finally

```
tab.selectedIndex = sender.tag
```

And remove this part completely as it a new instance

```
let board = UIStoryboard.init(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
let tabbar = board.instantiateViewController(identifier: "mainTabBar") as! MainTabBarController
```